# How to make a long list of choices for a CharField in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a text file containing the names of courses. I'd like them to become choices in my model. But I'm not sure how to populate COURSE_CHOICES. It looks like the choices will be hardcoded. But the choices need to be editable.

All I have currently is the following:

```
COURSE_CHOICES = ?????

class Course(models.Model):
    ... 
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

I'm new. All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have tried to do something like `choices=get_choices_from_file`? Where `get_choices_from_file` is a method that returns all choices in the right format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure what you want to achieve. But storing all courses in a model is a smart thing to do:

```
# models.py
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

# python manage.py shell
from myapp.models import Course

path = "path/to/file.txt"
data = open(path, 'r').read()
course_list = data.split()

for i in course_list:
    c = Course(title=i)
    c.save()
```

When you create a (normal) form you can use a `ModelChoiceField`:

```
course = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Crouse.objects.all(), 
                                empty_label="(Nothing)")
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Or create a `modelForm`:

```
class CourseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Note: I didn't test the code.

Comment: Hey man, just wanted to say thanks I had to edit your code a little, but I finally got it working after fixing my database, thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. You may accept the answer and if you find it useful press the arrow up! ;) Happy coding!

Comment: I would love to press the arrow up, but my rep is too low and this question didn't put me off to a good start because it is currently -1 lol. Thanks though I really appreciate it.

Comment: The idea of Stack Overflow is that questions and their answers are also useful for others. Therefore it is important that questions have a certain quality. Somebody didn't think your Q is a good contribution. You earn rep by all kinds of things. Like reading the about page ;). You could accept the answer... Hit check mark (and check your rep).

Answer (score 1):

Open and read the file then and:

```
file = open('myfile.txt') 
COURSE_CHOICES = tuple((choice,choice) for choice in file.readline())
```

I don't know how your file is structured...so this is all I can say.

Comment: I've tried something similar but ill try that I'm new to python/django and that looks like what I want.  My file is constructed line by line, so every line is a "course"/choice